# Limit Database Items To Which I Don't Have Access

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I created a few databases within a large hosting provider network.  When I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to connect to the SQL instance I see a list of every SQL database on the server.  Is there a way I can tell Management Studio to only display the tables I have access to?

I found a few articles online that said to deny my user the permission to view the other databases.  That wouldn't be an issue, except I don't think I can do that from my end.  I'd like to solve my problem without having to call my hosting provider.  Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are asking is NOT possible at this time. I know this is NOT what you are looking for :-)